# How to edit datepicker/day.html from uib-datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

In the documentation for `uib-datepicker` there is an option called `template-url`

```
<-- https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker -->
```

This is the content:

```
<div ng-switch="datepickerMode" role="application" ng-keydown="keydown($event)">
<uib-daypicker ng-switch-when="day" tabindex="0"></uib-daypicker>
<uib-monthpicker ng-switch-when="month" tabindex="0"></uib-monthpicker>
<uib-yearpicker ng-switch-when="year" tabindex="0"></uib-yearpicker>
</div>
```

But I need modify the template from "uib-daypicker"; I tried copying the template from `datepicker/day.html` but it's not working because it's a directive... so, what do I have to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**----EDITED----**

Into the library ui-bootstrap-tpls are all the templates:

- datepicker.html
- day.html
- month.html
- year.html

datepicker.html :

```
<div class="uib-datepicker" ng-switch="datepickerMode" role="application" ng-keydown="keydown($event)">
    <uib-daypicker ng-switch-when="day" tabindex="0"></uib-daypicker>
    <uib-monthpicker ng-switch-when="month" tabindex="0"></uib-monthpicker>
    <uib-yearpicker ng-switch-when="year" tabindex="0"></uib-yearpicker>
</div>
```

day.html:

```
<table class="uib-daypicker" role="grid" aria-labelledby="{{::uniqueId}}-title" aria-activedescendant="{{activeDateId}}">
  <thead>
    <tr>
          <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left uib-left" ng-click="move(-1)" tabindex="-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button></th>
          <th colspan="{{::5 + showWeeks}}"><button id="{{::uniqueId}}-title" role="heading" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm uib-title" ng-click="toggleMode()" ng-disabled="datepickerMode === maxMode" tabindex="-1"><strong>{{title}}</strong></button></th>
          <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right uib-right" ng-click="move(1)" tabindex="-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button></th>
        </tr>
    <tr>
          <th ng-if="showWeeks" class="text-center"></th>
          <th ng-repeat="label in ::labels track by $index" class="text-center"><small aria-label="{{::label.full}}">{{::label.abbr}}</small></th>
        </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="uib-weeks" ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index">
      <td ng-if="showWeeks" class="text-center h6"><em>{{ weekNumbers[$index] }}</em></td>
      <td ng-repeat="dt in row" class="uib-day text-center" role="gridcell"
        id="{{::dt.uid}}"
        ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"
          uib-is-class="
            'btn-info' for selectedDt,
            'active' for activeDt
            on dt"
          ng-click="select(dt.date)"
          ng-disabled="::dt.disabled"
          tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}">{{::dt.label}}</span></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

moth.html:

```
<table class="uib-monthpicker" role="grid" aria-labelledby="{{::uniqueId}}-title" aria-activedescendant="{{activeDateId}}">
  <thead>
    <tr>
          <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left uib-left" ng-click="move(-1)" tabindex="-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button></th>
          <th><button id="{{::uniqueId}}-title" role="heading" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm uib-title" ng-click="toggleMode()" ng-disabled="datepickerMode === maxMode" tabindex="-1"><strong>{{title}}</strong></button></th>
          <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right uib-right" ng-click="move(1)" tabindex="-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button></th>
        </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="uib-months" ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index">
      <td ng-repeat="dt in row" class="uib-month text-center" role="gridcell"
        id="{{::dt.uid}}"
        ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
          uib-is-class="
            'btn-info' for selectedDt,
            'active' for ativeDt
            on dt"
          ng-click="select(dt.date)"
          ng-disabled="::dt.disabled"
          tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-info': dt.current}">{{::dt.label}}</span></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

year.html:

```
<table class="uib-yearpicker" role="grid" aria-labelledby="{{::uniqueId}}-title" aria-activedescendant="{{activeDateId}}">
  <thead>
    <tr>
          <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left uib-left" ng-click="move(-1)" tabindex="-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button></th>
          <th colspan="{{::columns - 2}}"><button id="{{::uniqueId}}-title" role="heading" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm uib-title" ng-click="toggleMode()" ng-disabled="datepickerMode === maxMode" tabindex="-1"><strong>{{title}}</strong></button></th>
          <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right uib-right" ng-click="move(1)" tabindex="-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button></th>
        </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="uib-years" ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index">
      <td ng-repeat="dt in row" class="uib-year text-center" role="gridcell"
        id="{{::dt.uid}}"
        ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
          uib-is-class="
            'btn-info' for selectedDt,
            'active' for activeDt
            on dt"
          ng-click="select(dt.date)"
          ng-disabled="::dt.disabled"
          tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-info': dt.current}">{{::dt.label}}</span></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So if you need change any one of those templates you just use the attribute template-url, for example:

```
<div class="uib-datepicker" ng-switch="datepickerMode" role="application" ng-keydown="keydown($event)">
    <uib-daypicker ng-switch-when="day" template-url="template/route/template-day.html" tabindex="0"></uib-daypicker>
    <uib-monthpicker ng-switch-when="month" template-url="template/route/template-moth.html" tabindex="0"></uib-monthpicker>
    <uib-yearpicker ng-switch-when="year" template-url="template/route/template-year.html" tabindex="0"></uib-yearpicker>
</div>
```

Only make your changes on the original templates.
Pd: Sorry about my english isn't my native language.

Comment: Should this be an edit to your original post? Can't se an answer here, but I you found one I would be interested, since I've the same problem.

Comment: I improved the answer, so I hope this works for you @jowey

Comment: thank you for your response and your effort, but changing my dependencies directely isn't a solution for me. I'm searching for a solution with the dateOptions: datepicker-template-url and datepicker-popup-template-url. This could also be interesting for you.

Comment: Is it possible to modify "day.html" to add heading for year + current selected date?